# Stream deflate with PHP

Tags: php, zlib

I have a C program that communicate on a socket compressing/decompressing every packet with zlib. It creates a z_stream object and compress every packet with "deflate" and flushing it.

In PHP I can't decompress correctly these packets because the gzuncompress and gzinflate have no compression state (z_stream). The first packet is decompressed correctly, the following not.
I tried gzopen/gzread but they are not working for this case.

Is there a way to incrementally compress/decompress in PHP?